# how my function can be undefind with firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have my function on my class and i have to catch my subcollection. everything works fine with my collection (my console.log is working) but when i tried to catch something on my subcollection i have this error :

> TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...(0, _firestore.default)().collection("Teams").doc(docid).collection("membersList").where("statut", "==", "Validé").then...')

also my code :

```
GetMembersTeam = async () => {
    firestore()
      .collection("Teams")
      .where("tokenTeam", "==", "c2z3f4vb3bh")
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        if (querySnapshot.empty) {
          console.log("no documents found");
        } else {
          querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            let Teams = doc._data;
            let docid = doc.id;
            firestore()
              .collection("Teams")
              .doc(docid)
              .collection("membersList")

              .where("statut", "==", "Validé")
              .then(async (querySnapshot) => {
                if (querySnapshot.empty) {
                  console.log("no documents found");
                } else {
                  querySnapshot.forEach(async (doc) => {
                    let Teams = doc._data;
                    let docid = doc.id;
                    console.log(docid);
                  });
                }
              });
          });
        }
      });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.GetViewTeam();
    this.GetMembersTeam();
  }
```

Comment: what do you mean you try to catch something

Comment: catch my documents with statut == "Validé", i used to do it by Hook but this time when i tried on my class components it doesn't works

Comment: maybe because missing a .get() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you missing a `get()`?

```
firestore()
              .collection("Teams")
              .doc(docid)
              .collection("membersList")
              .where("statut", "==", "Validé")
              .get() //<- are you missing a get?
              .then(async (querySnapshot) => {
                if (querySnapshot.empty) {
                  console.log("no documents found");
                } else {
                  querySnapshot.forEach(async (doc) => {
                    let Teams = doc._data;
                    let docid = doc.id;
                    console.log(docid);
                  });
                }
```